# Verify two successive method calls invoke mock method with a different parameters at each time

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to verify that, a method in my moq mock object will be called upon two successive API calls. And each time with a different parameter.

Is that possible?

e.g. I want my code look like this:

```
mock.Verify(mock => mock.Display(firstColor));
mock.Verify(mock => mock.Display(secondColor));
Assert.AreNotEqual(firstColor, secondColor);
```

Comment: Does the order of the method calls matter?

Comment: Also do you know the exact name of the different parameters that has been called in the successive API calls? Or they just happen to be 2 different parameters?

Comment: @Spock The order doesn't matter. I don't know the exact name of parameters. I hope I can put a placeholder there and save the value from. So I can compare it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is needed to collect all passed parameters into `List<string> colours` variable to be able to verify them then.

```
[TestMethod]
public void MethodCallsTest()
{
    // arrange
    var mock = new Mock<IObjectToMock>();
    var colours = new List<string>();
    mock
        .Setup(it => it.Display(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Callback<string>(colour => colours.Add(colour));

    // act
    /* Any code that invokes method 'Display'.
       Direct call the method is the simplest way to test. */
    mock.Object.Display("red");
    mock.Object.Display("green");

    // assert
    colours.Count.Should().Be(2);
    /* Any assertions that are needed */
    colours.ForEach(colour => mock.Verify(it => it.Display(colour)));
    Assert.AreNotEqual(colours[0], colours[1]);
}

public interface IObjectToMock
{
    void Display(string colour);
}
```

Comment: Looks good I think it is very close. I was leaning towards a similar solution but then wondered "how can I really say the SUT calls the same method with 2 'different' parameters. I your test you are 'setting up' two different parameters.

Comment: I hope that real SUT calls Display() twice with different parameters. Since I know nothing about real SUT I decided simply call mock.Object.Display() twice in the test.

Comment: Your solution is good. I was doing the same with SUT, but your solution can apply even the SUT uses the same mock object. Nice solution.